# Почему findFragmentById возвращает null?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Объясните пожалуйста, почему `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)` возвращает null если в классе  SingleFragmentActivity он добавляется в FragmentManager?

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
}
```

.

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentManager fm= getSupportFragmentManager();
    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
           Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
           if (fragment == null) {
               fragment = createFragment();
               fm.beginTransaction()
                       .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                       .commit();
           }
       }
}
```

.

```
public class MyActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Возвращает null
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    }
    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new MyFragment();
    }
}
```

Comment: `R.id.fragment_container` не фрагмент, а `FrameLayout`. Как фрагмент он его не находит, отсюда - `null`

Comment: Я понимаю что FrameLayout это не фрагмент, а  контейнер для фрагмента, но насколько я понял метод add(R.id.container, fragment) добавляет фрагмент в список фрагметов FragmentManager'a и обеспечивает однозначную идентификацию фрагмента с его контейнером  в списке FragmentManager, а метод findFragmentById должен найти фрагмент в соответствии с его контейнерным идентификатором в FragmentManagere так как он был туда добавлен.

Comment: Ведь если спровоцировать MyAcrivity запустить метод OnCreat повторно, например перевернуть экран в альбомную и обратно, то в классе SingleFragmentActivity не сработает условие if(fragment=null) так как фрагмент уже был добавлен в список франметов FragmentManager'a при первом запуске метода OnCreat класса MyActivity и он найдет его с помощью findFragmentById.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов [`commit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()) не выполняет транзакцию немедленно, а ставит в очередь UI-потока.
Поэтому следующий за ним вызов `findFragmentById` выполняется раньше, чем фрагмент будет добавлен.
Вместо этого можно завершить транзакцию синхронным методом [`commitNow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitNow()) - тогда всё выполнится по порядку.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment class="com.example.mycompany.mycontainer"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </fragment>
 <FrameLayout/>
```

Вот так вот у меня находит фрагмент